# Integrating react-native with existing app with buildToolsVersion 24

Tags: android, react-native, android-appcompat, react-android

I'm trying to integrate react-native into an existing Android application, but keep running into the following error:

```
> Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1.
```

It seems like react-native needs sdkBuildTools version 23.0.1 and appcompat-v7 version 23.0.1.

However, the application I'm working on depends on sdkBuildTools version 24 and also appcompat-v7 version 23.2. Downgrading these dependencies is not an option.

Does this mean I can't integrate react-native into the app without rebuilding react-native from source with bumped up dependencies?

Comment: when you change build version.. you should clean cache.. react-native start --reset-cache

Answer (score 0):

Go to android SDK manager and install build tool version 23.2 and change sdkBuildTools of every gradle in your project to 24 and also it will ask you after install that you have new version of SDK tools installed would you like to change the configuration, you can click on it .. If not then reach out to your app's gradle and change the appcompact version

One last step you need to do is change classpath version of your project and that will be notified by the android studio or i think 2.3.0 would be merely fine.

Cheers :)